# How to check if message contains anything else?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Basically, your message contains the word "Will". I want to check if the message contains anything other than will. Here is my code:

```
if(msg.content.startsWith("Will")) {
    if (!msg.length) {
       console.log("Nothing other than "Will")
    }
}
```

Can anyone else help? Thanks alot.

Comment: Check if `message.content === 'Will'`. This will return true if the message is exclusively "Will". For more advanced queries, use a RegExp and `<RegExp>.test(message.content)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the `message.content`. If `message.content` is not `Will` so do anything.

```
    if(msg.content === 'Will'){
       console.log("Nothing other than "Will")
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not look correct. If `content.startsWith("Will")` then `content.includes("Will")` will always be true

Comment: Yes sorry I just changed it.

Comment: Why check if the content starts with "Will" *and then* check if the content is equal to "Will"? It looks like you added an extra step. Just check if the content is equal to "Will".

Comment: The first if statement is redundant. Also, a tip: lowercase the message content to accept different kinds of userinputs for `Will`, unless you really want the user to have the desired input which is in this case `Will` with uppercase W.

Comment: Yes i have changet it.

Comment: @Variable @Lioness100 I would keep the first `if` statement. That way the code respects the same structure as the question. It looks as if the asked may have removed some code in order to provide a minimally-reproducible example, and keeping the same structure may help the asker understand the answer better.